# Theorem about ARMA process existing

Tags: arma

I have met the theorem:

"For each stationary time series there is ARMA model with finite number of parameters."

Could you indicate official source with proof (bibligraphy) of this theorem?

Comment: I don't believe there can be a theorem exactly as stated (specifically, the 'finite number of parameters' would seem to be a probelm). Where did you encounter it?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a theorem, it has to be related to the inversion theorem: For every (weakly) stationary time series there is a representation as an AR process.  (Note that this may be an infinite AR.)